# Find MAX Number from a String List with C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a string list having characters with numbers. I just wanted to split the string to get the number and later I need to find the max number from that splitted number list.

**Match String**

```
abc
```

**Example List Values**

```
abc9
abc100
abc999
abc
```

**Result**

```
abc1000
```

**I have tried the below code**

```
string Result="";
var SF = (from site in db.SF where site.Code == "xyz" select site.Line2).FirstOrDefault();   // Here I ll get "abc"
                    int Count = (from Ps in db.Ps where Ps.No.StartsWith(SF) select Ps.No).ToList().Count;
                    if (Count != 0)
                    {
                        var PNo = (from Ps in db.Ps where Ps.No.StartsWith(SF) select Ps.No).ToList().LastOrDefault();
                        if (PNo != null)
                        {
                            int Val = Convert.ToInt32(PNo.Replace(SF, "")) + 1;  // Here I need to get `abc1000` based on the above ex. list.
                            Res = SF + Val.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Result = SF + "1";
                    }
```

When I execute the code, It always comes with "abc10" after It reached "abc45". Any help in providing the generic logic will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: From where you are getting `abc1000` as the MAX

Comment: Its an example of what i am looking for. I need to get `abc1000` when the MAX value in the list is `abc999`.

Comment: So you mean that `MAX+1` is your expected result

Comment: @SivaCharan. Yes .. Thats right .. Also, if `abc` is the only one value in the list, then it should come up with `abc1`.

Comment: @Deva , what if its abc994 ? i don't think you want abc995.. are you looking for rounding to nearest 10

Comment: @tariq. I want to get `abc995` if my MAX value is `abc994`. I am for MAX+1 always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
var myStrings = new List<string>();
            myStrings.Add("abc9");
            myStrings.Add("abc100");
            myStrings.Add("abc999");
            myStrings.Add("abc");

            var maxNumber = "abc" + (from myString in myStrings let value = Regex.Match(myString, @"\d+").Value select Convert.ToInt32(value == string.Empty ? "0" : Regex.Match(myString, @"\d+").Value) + 1).Concat(new[] { 0 }).Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OrderByDescending()` to get the biggest number and then add `+1` to result

```
var result = (from Ps in db.Ps 
                where Ps.No.StartsWith(SF) 
                select Ps.No)
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.PS.No)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I tried it and it seems to do what you are describing.

```
public static string testString(string[] input, string startString)
    {
        int max = 0;
        try
        {
            max = input.Where(s => s.StartsWith(startString) && s.Length > startString.Length)
                       .Max(s => int.Parse(s.Replace(startString, string.Empty)));
        }
        catch
        {
            // no worries, this means max was "abc" without a number
        }
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", startString, (max + 1).ToString());

    }
```

call it with

```
string test = testString(new string[] { "abc1", "abc123", "abc23", "xyz23" }, "abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below mentioned code to get the Max number from your List

```
var max = myList.Select(v => int.Parse(v.Substring(3))).Max();
```